# Docker NodeJS Azure ServiceBus Service Lock Timeout

Tags: azure, docker, timeout, locking, servicebus

Apart from changing "Lock Duration" setting in Azure Portal, I want to know how to set the timeout value/ renew lock mechanism. (Better to handle unknown long running tasks)

```js
var azure = require('azure-sb'),
    serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService("Endpoint=XXX");
serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage(MESSAGE_QUEUE_NAME, { isPeekLock: true }, function(error, lockedMessage){
... task running longer than "Lock Duration" ...
}
```

When finish, there is error and the message is moved to Deadletter Queue:

> Error: 404 - The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or
>   the message has already been removed from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use [renewLockForMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-sb/servicebusservice?view=azure-node-latest#renewlockformessage-message--callback-) to extend the lock.

Hope it helps!